# What is the cost of having a class within a class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, organization, code-organization

I am trying to create classes within a class in swift so I can more easily access variables by their category. For example my renderer has many pipelines so it might be nice to be able to go `pipelines.<whateverPipelineINeed>` or my builder might have various pipelines it can build so I might want to go `Builder.pipelines.<whatEverPipelineINeed>()`.

This has prompted me to generate code looking like the following

```
class Renderer: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {
    let device:MTLDevice!
    let queue:MTLCommandQueue!
    let depth:MTLDepthStencilState!

    class Pipelines {
        static var defaultTriangles:MTLRenderPipelineState!
        static var fancyTriangles:MTLRenderPipelineState!
    }
    .......
}
```

or

```
class Builder {
    class func loadTexture(device: MTLDevice,
                           textureName: String) -> MTLTexture? {
        ...
    }

    class PipelineStates {
        class func blankTriangle(device: MTLDevice) -> MTLRenderPipelineState? {
            ...
        }

        class func fancyTriangle(device: MTLDevice) -> MTLRenderPipelineState? {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Of course there are much more than just 2 of these pipelines and I am using this pattern for other objects. Additionally there is not a pattern where  = builder.() as some of the objects get initialized frequently. Additionally I do check for errors in the compilation with the optional type.

Is this an ok way to do things in swift? Is there any cost of inefficiency related to doing things like this that I should know about?

Additionally is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use struct? There is no need to use class when you are not inheriting anything. Also Structs over Classes...

Comment: @DominikBucher great idea but that doesnt work as well for example when I try to set the struct it says "Instance Member 'defaultTriangles' cannot be used on type 'Render.Pipelines' and a similar error pops up for the builder

Comment: Well because it is an instance member and not static property of that class. you see if you set the instance static and instantiate it, it's fine...

Comment: Also if you are facing this problem and you have static variables inside the class.. consider enum with static variables inside, it is very useful.

Comment: There are most definitely reasons to use a class even if not inheriting anything.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Since Swift is protocol oriented language, it makes classes less flexible in many ocassions. For instance with struct you can conform to multiple protocols having some extension on that protocol to do things you desire. Not speaking of copying over making references... I strongly suggest to watch this speak at wwdc. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/

Comment: I agree there are more reasons in Swift to use a struct than a class than perhaps there are in other languages.  Your original comment was that 'there is no need to use a class when you are not inheriting' and all I said is that there are reasons to use a class when you are not inheriting.  You can also have a class conform to multiple protocols with an extension on the protocol.  For example you would use classes if you want just a singe instance of something that is shared app wide.  I have already seen that WWDC video as I have with most of the other videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it into enums

```swift
public enum Pipeline {

    public enum PipelineName: String {
        case defaultTriangles
        case fancyTriangles
    }

    case defaultTriangles(MTLRenderPipelineState)
    case fancyTriangles(MTLRenderPipelineState)

    public var pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState {
        switch self {
        case .defaultTriangles(let pipeline): return pipeline
        case .fancyTriangles(let pipeline): return pipeline
        }
    }

    public init?(withDevice device: MTLDevice,
                 library: MTLLibrary,
                 pipelineName: PipelineName) {
        switch pipelineName {
        case .defaultTriangles:
            let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
            // Set descriptor properties
            guard
                let pipelineState = try? device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
                else {
                    return
            }
            self = .defaultTriangles(pipelineState)
        case .fancyTriangles: 
            let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
            // Set descriptor properties
            guard
                let pipelineState = try? device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
                else {
                    return
            }
            self = .defaultTriangles(pipelineState)
        }
    }

}
```

Then initialize like so:

```swift
guard 
    let pipeline = Pipeline(withDevice: device,
                            library: library,
                            pipelineName: .defaultTriangles)
    else { return }
self.defaultPipeline = pipeline
```

Then later on when you need to render access the pipeline like so:

```swift
self.defaultPipeline.pipeline
/// Execute commands and set arguments / etc.
```

Also what would be cool to do would be to define a render pass with infix operators:

```swift
defaultTriangles |--> triangleComputationPipeline |--> fancyTriangles
```

Comment: Is this actually "a better way" or just "another way"? Isn't the question a bit unclear and even opinion based?

Comment: Probably better in the sense that it encapsulates your code cleanly you can even create your own enums for your fragment and vertex shaders.